# Como faço para pegar os dados de um select option enviar para um email o valor selecionado

Tags: php

**HTML:**

```
<form action="orcamento.php" method="POST">

  <div id="fh5co-contact" class="animate-box">

    <div class="grid_15">
      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="nome_do_projeto" placeholder="NOME DO PROJETO">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="descreva_o_projeto" placeholder="DESCREVA O PROJETO">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="qual_seu_orcamento" placeholder="QUAL SEU ORÇAMENTO">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="quantos_metros_tem_seu_projeto" placeholder="QUANTOS METROS TEM SEU PROJETO?">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_15 ajust_19">


      <div class="grid_4 ajusta_lg_1">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label class="ajusta_lg_2" for="male">CASA COMPLETA</label>
          <select class="ajsta_rl" name="departamento1">
            <option value="Decoraração Completa">Decoração Completa</option>
            <option value="Doecoraçã Parcial">Decoração Parcial</option>
            <option value="Nada a Mudar">Nada a mudar</option>
          </select>
          <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo do veículo"-->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajusta_lg_1">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label class="ajusta_lg_2" for="male">COZINHA</label>
          <select class="ajsta_rl" name="departamento2">
            <option value="Decoração Completa">Decoração Complea</option>
            <option value="Decoração Parcial">Decoração Parcial</option>
            <option value="Parede Única">Parede Única</option>
            <option value="Formato em L">Formato em L</option>
            <option value="Formato em U">Formato em U</option>
            <option value="Nada a Mudar">Nada a Mudar</option>
          </select>
          <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo do veículo"-->
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="grid_4 ajusta_lg_1">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label class="ajusta_lg_2" for="male">SALA DE ESTAR</label>
          <select class="ajsta_rl" name="departamento3">
            <option value="Decoração Completa">Decoraração Completa</option>
            <option value="Decoração Parcial">Decoraração Parcial</option>
            <option value="Nada a Mudar">Nada a Mudar</option>
          </select>
          <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo do veículo"-->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="grid_15 ajust_19">


      <div class="grid_4 ajusta_lg_1">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label class="ajusta_lg_2" for="male">BANHEIROS</label>
          <select class="ajsta_rl" name="departamento4">
            <option value="Decoração Completa">Decoração Completa</option>
            <option value="Decoração Parcial">Decoração Parcial</option>
            <option value="Moderno">Moderno</option>
            <option value="Campestre">Campestre</option>
            <option value="Clássico">Clássico</option>
            <option value="Rustíco">Rustíco</option>
            <option value="Nada a Mudar">Nada a Mudar</option>
          </select>
          <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo do veículo"-->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajusta_lg_1">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label class="ajusta_lg_2" for="male">QUARTOS</label>
          <select class="ajsta_rl" name="departamento5">
            <option value="Decoração Parcial">Decoração Completa</option>
            <option value="Decoração Parcial">Dcoração Parcial</option>
            <option value="Nada a Mudar">Nada a Mudar</option>
          </select>
          <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo do veículo"-->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4  ajusta_lg_1">
        <div class="form-group">

          <label class="ajusta_lg_2" for="male">COMERCIAL ESCRITÓRIO</label>
          <select class="ajsta_rl" name="departamento6">
            <option value="Decoração Completa">Decoração Completa</option>
            <option value="Decoração Parcial">Dcoração Parcial</option>
            <option value="Nada a Mudar">Nada a Mudar</option>
          </select>
          <!--input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo do veículo"-->
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--fin grid_15-->

    <div class="grid_15 ajust_19">


      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="nome_completo" id="nome_completo" placeholder="NOME COMPLETO">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="cidade" id="cidade" placeholder="CIDADE">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="estado" id="estado" placeholder="ESTADO [ UF ] ">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control ajust_18" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="TLEFONE">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_4 ajust_17">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control ajust_18" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="E-MAIL">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--fin grid_15-->

    <div class="grid_15">


      <div class="grid_3 ajust_22">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Receba uma cotação" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--fin grid_15-->

  </div>
  <!--fin fhrco-cantact-->
</form>
<!--fin form-->
```

**Código *PHP*:**

```
<?php
 //variaveis

 $equipe = 'Lucilene Bredoff';
 $quebra_linha = "\n\r";


 $departamento1 =    $_POST['casa_completa'];
 $departamento2 =    $_POST['cozinha'];
 $departamento3 =    $_POST['sala_de_estar'];
 $departamento4 =    $_POST['banheiros'];
 $departamento5 =    $_POST['quartos'];
 $departamento6 =    $_POST['comercial_escritorio'];

$emailremetente     = trim($_POST['email']);
$emaildestinatario  = 'diogo@zayin.site'; // Digite seu e-mail aqui, lembrando que o e-mail deve estar em seu servidor web
 //$email_to = 'diogo@zayin.site';  email para envio.
 $nome_do_projeto                     = $_POST["nome_do_projeto"];
 $descreva_o_projeto                  = $_POST["descreva_o_projeto"];
 $qual_seu_orcamento                  = $_POST["qual_seu_orcamento"];
 $quantos_mentros_tem_seu_projeto     = $_POST["quantos_metros_tem_seu_projeto"];
 $nome_completo                       = $_POST["nome_completo"];
 $cidade                              = $_POST["cidade"];
 $estado                              = $_POST["estado"];
 $telefone                            = $_POST["telefone"];
 $mail                                = $_POST["mail"];


 //$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
 //$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8".$quebra_linha;
 $headers .= "Nome do Projeto: $nome_do_projeto".$quebra_linha; 
 $headers .= "Remetente: $mail".$quebra_linha;
 $headers .= "From: $emailremetente\r\n"; // remetente
 $headers .= "Return-Path: $emaildestinatario \r\n"; // return-path
 //$headers .= "From: $emailremetente;".$quebra_linha;
 //$headers .= "Reply-To:".$departamento .$quebra_linha;
 //$headers .= "Retrun-Path:".$emaildestinatario .$quebra_linha;


$corpo     = "<strong>Projetos Online - Lucilene Bredoff</strong>\n";
$corpo    .= "Nome Do Projeto : "                  .$nome_do_projeto . "\n";
$corpo    .= "Descreva O Projeto : "               .$descreva_o_projeto. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Qual Seu Orçamento : "               .$qual_seu_orcamento. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Quantos Metros Tem Seu Projeto : "   .$quantos_mentros_tem_seu_projeto. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Nome Completo: "                     .$nome_completo. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Cidade: "                            .$cidade. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Estado: "                            .$estado. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Telefone :"                          .$telefone. "\n";
$corpo    .= "E-mail : "                           .$mail . "\n";



$status = mail($departamento1,$departamento2,$departamento3,$departamento4,$departamento5,$departamento6,$nome_do_projeto,$headers,$corpo); //enviando o email.

if ($status) {
  echo "<script>alert('$nome_completo, recebemos sua mensagem e retornaremos em breve, atenciosamente, $equipe .');location.href='index.html' </script>";  
}
else {
  echo "<script>alert('$nome_completo, sua mensagem não foi enviada, verifique se os campos foram preenchidos corretamente.');location.href='projetos_online.html'</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Olá Diogo, esplique melhor sua dúvida, não coloque apenas código. E verifique também a formatação dos códigos.

Comment: É a mesma coisa de enviar um *input*: `$derpatamento1 = $_POST['derpatamento1'];`

Comment: Eu ja tentei passar desta forma mas o    $status = mail($departamento1,$departamento2,$departamento3,$departamento4,$departamento5,$departamento6,$nome_do_projeto,$headers,$corpo); //enviando o email. da erro nesta linha  e não envia o e-mail.

Comment: @DavidAlves O que preciso e pegar os itens que estão no select passados pelo option  como exemplo  <select name="departamento"> <option valeu="Decoração Compelta">Decoração completa <option> </select>  e enviar para um e-mail

Comment: Acontece que, no seu código, você está utilizando `$departamento1 = $_POST['casa_completa'];`, porém não existe um campo com o atributo `name="casa_completa"`

Comment: O correto é `$departamento1 = $_POST['departamento1'];`

Comment: usei esta modificação mas continuo tendo erro de retorno na linha $status = mail($departamento1,$departamento2,$departamento3,$departamento4,$departamento5,$departamento6,$nome_do_projeto,$headers,$corpo); //enviando o email.

Comment: @DiogoCunha Qual o erro?

Comment: Apresenta a mensagem Warning: mail()expect at most 5 parameters, 9 given in /home/lucilenebredoff/public_html/orcamento.php on line 54

Retornando o else que passei informando do preenchimento dos campos

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
 //variaveis

 $equipe = 'Lucilene Bredoff';
 $quebra_linha = "\n\r";

 $departamento1 =    $_POST['departamento1'];
 $departamento2 =    $_POST['departamento2'];
 $departamento3 =    $_POST['departamento3'];
 $departamento4 =    $_POST['departamento4'];
 $departamento5 =    $_POST['departamento5'];




$emailremetente     = trim($_POST['email']);
$emaildestinatario  = 'diogo@zayin.site'; // Digite seu e-mail aqui, lembrando que o e-mail deve estar em seu servidor web
 //$email_to = 'diogo@zayin.site';  email para envio.
 $nome_do_projeto                     = $_POST["nome_do_projeto"];
 $descreva_o_projeto                  = $_POST["descreva_o_projeto"];
 $qual_seu_orcamento                  = $_POST["qual_seu_orcamento"];
 $quantos_mentros_tem_seu_projeto     = $_POST["quantos_metros_tem_seu_projeto"];
 $nome_completo                       = $_POST["nome_completo"];
 $cidade                              = $_POST["cidade"];
 $estado                              = $_POST["estado"];
 $telefone                            = $_POST["telefone"];
 $mail                                = $_POST["mail"];


 //$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1".$quebra_linha;
 //$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8".$quebra_linha;
 $headers .= "Nome do Projeto: $nome_do_projeto".$quebra_linha; 
 $headers .= "Remetente: $mail".$quebra_linha;
 $headers .= "From: $emailremetente\r\n"; // remetente
 $headers .= "Return-Path: $emaildestinatario \r\n"; // return-path
 //$headers .= "From: $emailremetente;".$quebra_linha;
 //$headers .= "Reply-To:".$departamento .$quebra_linha;
 //$headers .= "Retrun-Path:".$emaildestinatario .$quebra_linha;


$corpo     = "<strong>Projetos Online - Lucilene Bredoff</strong>\n";
$corpo    .= "Nome Do Projeto : "                  .$nome_do_projeto . "\n";
$corpo    .= "Descreva O Projeto : "               .$descreva_o_projeto. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Qual Seu Orçamento : "               .$qual_seu_orcamento. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Quantos Metros Tem Seu Projeto : "   .$quantos_mentros_tem_seu_projeto. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Nome Completo: "                     .$nome_completo. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Cidade: "                            .$cidade. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Estado: "                            .$estado. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Telefone :"                          .$telefone. "\n";
$corpo    .= "E-mail : "                           .$mail . "\n";
$corpo    .= "Casa Completa:"                      .$departamento1. "\n";  
$corpo    .= "Cozinha: "                           .$departamento2. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Sala de Estar: "                     .$departamento3. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Banheiros: "                         .$departamento4. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Quartos: "                           .$departamento5. "\n";
$corpo    .= "Comercial Escritório: "              .$departamento6. "\n";



$status = mail($emaildestinatario,$nome_do_projeto,$headers,$corpo); //enviando o email.

if ($status) {
  echo "<script>alert('$nome_completo, recebemos sua mensagem e retornaremos em breve, atenciosamente, $equipe .');location.href='index.html' </script>";  
}
else {
  echo "<script>alert('$nome_completo, sua mensagem não foi enviada, verifique se os campos foram preenchidos corretamente.');location.href='projetos_online.html'</script>";
}
?>
```

Consegui resolver, agradeço a todos que ajudaram